# Vlookup, return only 2nd instance

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

Here is my formula currently (which works as is), it returns only the first instance, I would like to have a second column that returns only the second instance of the referenced cell (if there is no second reference than it should return blank).

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(H2&I2,Sheet1!G$1:H$65536,2,0),VLOOKUP(H2&I2,Sheet1!K$1:L$65536,2,0))
```

Ideally I need it to return the 3rd and 4th instance as well, but in a separate column without using an array formula, just a new formula.

Comment: It would be an array formula(uses Ctrl-Shift-Enter) or native array formula(Aggregate,Sumproduct,...).  Are you trying to avoid array formula in total or just ones that require the Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: @ScottCraner I'm trying to avoid array formulas that use ctrl shift enter

Comment: Is there a specific reason for `$G$1:$H$65536` instead of `$G:$H`?  65536 was the maximum number of rows in `.xls` files (it is now 1048576 in `.xlsx` / `.xlsm` files), so is this just copy/paste from an old document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a non CSE array formula, it is entered normally:

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$H:$H,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(Sheet1!$G$1:INDEX(Sheet1!$G:$G,MATCH("zzz",Sheet1!$G:$G)))/(Sheet1!$G$1:INDEX(Sheet1!$G:$G,MATCH("zzz",Sheet1!$G:$G))=$H2&$I2),COLUMN(A:A))),INDEX(Sheet1!$L:$L,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(Sheet1!$K$1:INDEX(Sheet1!$K:$K,MATCH("zzz",Sheet1!$K:$K)))/(Sheet1!$K$1:INDEX(Sheet1!$K:$K,MATCH("zzz",Sheet1!$K:$K))=$H2&$I2),COLUMN(A:A)-COUNTIF(Sheet1!$G:$G,$H2&$I2)))),"")
```

Put this in the first cell and copy over till you get blanks.

This is untested.